# git - How can I obtain the branch name from which a pull request was initiated on github, while on my local machine?

Tags: git, github

I understand that a pull request started on Github can be fetched locally. It can be done in the following manner:

```
git fetch origin pull/*ID*/head
```

However, once I have done so, is there any way for me to obtain the branch name from which it had been initiated?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the pull request number (rather than the tip commit sha1) then you can browse to git hub and see what it says. From your remote's definition you should know the repo name.

e.g. here's one I raised a while back on the now back burnered msysgit https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/318

for me it tells me that

`PhilipOakley  wants to merge 14 commits into msysgit:maint-1.9 from PhilipOakley:msvc-build-fix` so I can see the two branch names (source/dest).

I'm not sure what happens if I delete that branch on Github...